# how to get data from JSON file in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I have 'modified_data.json' JSON file which has this structure.

```
{
"data": [
    [
        {
           "account_id": "  "
           "account_name": "   "
        },
        {
           "account_id": "  "
           "account_name": "   "
        },          
        {
           "account_id": "  "
           "account_name": "   "
        },          
        {
           "account_id": "  "
           "account_name": "   "
        }
     ],
     [
        {
           "account_id": "  "
           "account_name": "   "
        },
        {
           "account_id": "  "
           "account_name": "   "
        },
        {
           "account_id": "  "
           "account_name": "   "
        }
     ],
     [
        {
           "account_id": "  "
           "account_name": "   "
        },
        {
           "account_id": "  "
           "account_name": "   "
        },
        {
           "account_id": "  "
           "account_name": "   "
        }
      ]
   ]
}
```

I want to get first object's account_name from each array...

Does anyone can give me a solution??

Now I'm using Vue.js to display it, I could get each data with python, but Vue.js is not familiar with me yet... Kindly help me :)

Comment: Hi Yohan, welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please start by adding what you have tried? `I want to get first object's account_name from each array` sounds more like a Javascript question though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) that would reactively take `account_name` property of the first object of every array:

```js
const data = {
  "data": [
    [
      {
        "account_id": "11",
        "account_name": "name11"
      },
      {
        "account_id": "12",
        "account_name": "name12"
      },
      {
        "account_id": "13",
        "account_name": "name13"
      },
      {
        "account_id": "14",
        "account_name": "name14"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "account_id": "21",
        "account_name": "name21"
      },
      {
        "account_id": "22",
        "account_name": "name22"
      },
      {
        "account_id": "23",
        "account_name": "name23"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "account_id": "31",
        "account_name": "name31"
      },
      {
        "account_id": "32",
        "account_name": "name32"
      },
      {
        "account_id": "33",
        "account_name": "name33"
      }
    ]
  ]
}


new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      data: data.data
    }
  },
  computed: {
    firstAccountNames() {
      return this.data.map(dataSet => dataSet[0].account_name)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="name in firstAccountNames">
      {{ name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: one more question. If I put my json data into the script, it works..But when I try to read json file(same contents), console says error message always.

Firefox : SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Chrome : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

What should I do to load json file successfully?

Comment: @YohanChoi Probably your web app build tool (webpack I guess), automatically converts JSON into a JavaScript object. Try to remove manual parsing (`JSON.parse`) and simply use the imported data as a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 7):

Well, you will have to add the code that you have written for Vue

If you are in a vue app, you can do something like this

```
<script>
      import json from './json/data.json'
      export default{
          data(){
              return{
                  myJson: json
              }
          }
      }
</script>
```

and if you are writting it inside an html page. you can do it in 2 steps.

1st is to add the file link as a script

```
<script src="../file.json"></script>
```

then in the vue script section you can assign it to the data object.

```
var ele = new Vue({
     el : "#YourElement", 
    data : ObjName
});
```

"ObjName" is a name of the json object in the file.

```
ObjName :
{
"data": [
    [
        {
           "account_id": "  "
           "account_name": "   "
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) but I don't have ObjName for my json object..I want to get "account_name" of first object in each array. Is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it! here is code!

```
var app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    datas: []
},

computed: {
    getAccountNames() {
        return this.datas.map(dataSet => dataSet[0].account_name)
    }
},

mounted() {
    var self = this
    $.getJSON("modified_data.json", function(json_data) {
        self.datas = json_data.data
    })
  }
})
```

Anyway, another question...
what is the difference between "this" and "self" ?
"self" is equal to "this" I think but when I just use "this", it has error but "self" works well...anyone can tell me the difference?

Comment: Regarding this and self - the context of "this" changes within the callback of $.getJSON, and so "self" is just a custom named variable to capture the reference of "this" to be used later, before it's overridden within the callback context.